# How Can I call ShowForm from android native code?

Tags: java, android, mobile, cross-platform, codenameone

I am using codenameone where I need to do some native code in android but that invloves changing the content view and when I try to get the application to return to the codenameone forms , using the native code I end up with white screen ,

is there anyway that I could use `showForm` that codenameone handles navigation through from android native code  ??

After trying the bellow comments here is the log cat for the app while simulating the case :

`??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub bnds=[540,672][786,960]} from uid 10010 on display 0 from pid 1738
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Start proc 31254:com.mycompany.myapp/u0a352 for activity com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Gaining focus: Window{252c6842 u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [AppLaunch] Displayed Displayed com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub: +335ms
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Thread[1,tid=31254,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0x7facc9a000,peer=0x760befb0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/libopentok.so"
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Thread[1,tid=31254,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0x7facc9a000,peer=0x760befb0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/libopentok.so"
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Thread[1,tid=31254,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0x7facc9a000,peer=0x760befb0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/libopentok.so"
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Thread[1,tid=31254,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0x7facc9a000,peer=0x760befb0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/libopentok.so"
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Thread[1,tid=31254,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0x7facc9a000,peer=0x760befb0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1/lib/arm64/libopentok.so"
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): setMode: mode = 3; packageName = com.mycompany.myapp
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): setMode: mode = 0; packageName = com.mycompany.myapp
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.mycompany.myapp.VideoChat$1.run(Unknown Source)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Process: com.mycompany.myapp, PID: 31254
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.mycompany.myapp.NativeVideoChatImpl$VideoChat$4.onClick(NativeVideoChatImpl.java:234)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):   Force finishing activity 1 com.mycompany.myapp/.MyApplicationStub
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Losing focus: Window{252c6842 u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Process com.mycompany.myapp (pid 31254) has died
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): channel '252c6842 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): channel '252c6842 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): WIN DEATH: Window{252c6842 u0 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '252c6842 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplicationStub (server)'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all the senarios , I noticed that it actually get back to the form but the contents was not shown , so here is what I did since I encountered this issue in another app ,
the code was implemented in the native side 
-- tried to change the time period and when I go less the problem returns so that is good enough for me

```
getActivity().finish();
            intent = new Intent(getContext(), MyApplicationStub.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            handler = new Handler();
            timer = new Timer();    
            initializeTimerTask();
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 500);

public void initializeTimerTask() {

            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {

                    //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
```

Thanks to all your Help @JamesH and @Shai

Comment: @ShaiAlmog did that , but I didn't use that approach :) , fixed from native

Answer (score 3):

See the [advanced section in the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) titled "Native Code Callbacks".

Create a static method e.g. `showForm()` in the class where you create the form. In your native Android code you can call that method using the full package name of the class that implements the method e.g.: `com.mycompany.myapp.MyFormClass.showForm()`.

The class that implements the method then needs to have a reference to the form, so it could be the class that creates the form and keep a static reference to the form. To preserve memory, you may want to release the reference if the form is dismissed.

In iOS and other platforms follow the guidelines in the developer guide e.g. in this case for iOS `showForm()` would look like this (at the top of your `.m` file:

```
#include "com_mycompany_myapp_MyFormClass.h"
```

Then when you want to call `showForm()`:

```
com_mycompany_myapp_MyFormClass_showForm__(CN1_THREAD_STATE_PASS_SINGLE_ARG);
```

Comment: Good answer James, I edited it a bit to provide a sample to iOS as well and context to the developer guide

Comment: I tried that and it didn't call the static method it just froze since showForm not static here is the snippet of code that I used           `public static void showForm(){
  Dialog.show("hello", "testing if function called", null,null);
  UIBuilder ui=new UIBuilder();
  ui.setResourceFilePath("/theme");
  ui.showForm("Main", null);
    }`  @James H @Shai Almog

Comment: I also tried this way : `public static void showForm(){
  Dialog.show("hello", "testing if function called", null,null);
  UIBuilder ui=new UIBuilder();
  ui.setResourceFilePath("/theme");
  Form mainForm = (Form)ui.createContainer(ui.getResourceFilePath(), "Main");
  mainForm.show();
  //ui.showForm("Main", null);
    }`

Comment: I forgot to mention that you will probably need to wrap the call to show() in callSerially() so that it gets done on the EDT. The callback from Android is probably on a different thread.

Comment: well , I tried that `Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UIBuilder ui=new UIBuilder();
    ui.showForm("Main", null); 
   }
  });` still the app freezes and when press on the button again it crashes @James H

Comment: Can you post the native code? Is your package name actually "com.mycompany.myapp"?

Comment: Add something like `if(ui == null) { ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Null UI"); return; }`

Comment: @ShaiAlmog still the same the application crashes without the toast bar

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I checked the log and it is the same , the idea that in the native code I change the content view to match what I need to do , basically I have a video chat I created a class that act like a listener and post the streams to the container that I put in the content view , and I have a button to end the call , in that case I need to return to my original App

Comment: If you leave the method blank do you crash? Do you have a Mac/xcode?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog it didn't crash and as for Mac I could get one for testing

Comment: @ShaiAlmog is there anyway I could get the contentView Id for the form that I am calling the native code from , so when I change the contentView from the native ,  I can restore it by setting the contentView back to the Id of the previous form

Comment: The view is `[[CodenameOne_GLViewController instance] view]` you will need to add the import `#import "CodenameOne_GLViewController.h"` I'm assuming you are using the call serially call mentioned by James within that `run()` block surround the whole body with try/catch for throwable to make sure nothing fails there.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog ok that is for iOS but I am having the problem with Android , can't get it to restore the form to the previous one after changing the contentView

Comment: Android is easy if you are experiencing an issue there you can just plugin a cable and use logcat/ddms to look at the output and see if there is an exception or error. Should point you at the exact line number.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog yes solved on android but iOS can't seem to be able to open the native UIViewController , still I just started working on iOS part

Comment: Make sure you are on the native OS thread in iOS. Surround your native code with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // your code here.... });`